# Mapbox DeckGL react - Deck producing extra blank space when rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, deck.gl

I am writing a map feature in react.js using mapbox and DeckGL (chrome browser). I have read through the examples on the DeckGL website and am trying to produce a simple scatterplot layer (https://deck.gl/examples/scatterplot-layer) with a mapbox mapview (https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/base-maps/using-with-mapbox).
I can get everything to render and it's all working ok, except there is a bunch of empty space at the bottom of the page whenever I add the mapview within the DeckGL call (see code below). When I take out the map parts and leave just DeckGL with the scatter layer, the empty space is no longer there. I tried adding some basic style commands like setting paddingBottom to 0, marginBottom to 0, and display to inline for all the different elements, as well as adding outer boxes and setting position to relative, but alas the blank space is always there.

Played with various style settings like padding, margins, displays (inline), as well as put outer Box elements with 'position=relative' so that the children nodes inherit the Box'x dimensions (this actually worked for the right hand empty space but not for the bottom empty space).

I rendered the page in chrome with extra space, and then hunted through the elements listed in the dev tools and found that there is an extra canvas layer created then doubles in width whenever a mapview is added to the DeckGL element (hence why I tried setting display to inline). I tried also adding a call to this in a style sheet and playing with padding and margins etc like that but it also did not work.

Does someone know what I missed? I just know it's something simple XD

Thanks in advance!
Jon.

PS I know- I'm using functions and not classes for features but I'm a newbie...

```
import React from 'react';
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import { ScatterplotLayer } from '@deck.gl/layers';
import { MapView } from '@deck.gl/core';
import Map from 'react-map-gl';

// Viewport settings
const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
    longitude: -122.41669,
    latitude: 37.7853,
    zoom: 13,
    pitch: 0,
    bearing: 0
};

// Data to be used by the LineLayer
const data = [
    { coordinates: [-122.41669, 37.7853] }
];

function EventsMap({ Events = "", openMap = "", handleOpenMap = "" }) {
    const layers = [
        new ScatterplotLayer({
            id: 'scatterplot-layer',
            data,
            pickable: true,
            opacity: 0.8,
            stroked: true,
            filled: true,
            radiusScale: 6,
            radiusMinPixels: 50,
            radiusMaxPixels: 50,
            lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
            getPosition: d => d.coordinates,
            // getRadius: d => Math.sqrt(d.exits),
            getFillColor: d => [255, 140, 0],
            getLineColor: d => [0, 0, 0]
        })
    ];

    return (
        <DeckGL style={{ width: "50%", height: "50%", display: "inline" }}
            initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
            controller={true}
            layers={layers}
        >
            <MapView height="100%" id="map" controller={true}>
                < Map mapboxAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
                    mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9" />
            </MapView>
        </DeckGL >
    );
}
```